# Designing a ASP.net website - how do i make it look nice?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web

I'm about to make my first website in ASP.net, and I've been fooling around with the designer mode in VS 2010 ulti.

I really don't get how people can make a really nice website that looks and feels nice.

I mean, when I design something in the designer, it looks like pure HTML with textboxes and labels.

Do I have to insert panels and place pictures in them?

Or could any of you recommend a good website/tutorial for designing an ASP.Net website?

Just like this site: http://www.asp.net/. It looks really nice and dosen't have that "HTML look".

Any suggestions on how I should start?

Thx!

Comment: This is not a *programming* question, or even something that has a specific answer (required for SO). Perhaps http://doctype.com/ would be better: Q&A for Web Designers.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you're going to find an easy answer here. I work with graphic designers who have spent years learning and researching the best way to design a website from usability to accessibility, as well as being 'fashionable' etc.

As a programmer, I have little involvement in design (and when I do its rubbish!)

Comment: nice link... not much of a designer myself, but I think I'll give it a read.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET is not JUST about dragging and dropping stuff in the designer. I personally almost don't use drag/drop method. Switch to the 'source' view and type your html yourself. Also to make it look nice you need to know how you want it to look in the first place, and then play with CSS for your page...
Remember: HTML is the structure, CSS is the LOOK.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a good looking web site requires the ability to design, not the ability to use design tools.

Quality design is a skill, not something you can achieve simply by using a tool to place panels and graphics.

Therefore, if you want your site to look good, you need either:

- Hire a skilled graphic designer.
- Buy a template created by a skilled graphic designer.
- Study graphic design until you're skilled enough to do it yourself.

Of course, programming skills and user-interface are also important -- even the best looking graphic design will be spoiled if the site has poor UI or jerky animations, or has broken links, etc, but if you want your site to look good, start with quality graphic design.

Answer (score 1):

Go to [ThemeForest](http://themeforest.net/) and buy a theme that suits you.

Comment: You can check for MDBootstrap (it´s a front-end framework built on top of Bootstrap). There you will find an article with free ASP.NET templates.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it yourself, and just learning. Then you can do what i did in the beginning. Take one day doing some basic HTML and CSS here

http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Then learn basic fancy/modern stuff. do these

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/default.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/css3/default.asp

Do all of it on the same page, so you can see everything you have done afterwards, 
it makes it easier to get a understanding of what you can do afterwards.

this is a great way to get used to the tools in designing, you need HTML and CSS then

Answer (score 1):

I think you should start by making some solid features in your site. And then focus on making it look cool.

If you don't have the experience too see the design before the features are done, my suggestion can make it alot more clear. Yes, you might have to do a little refactoring, but on the other hand your are more likely to get a good solid result everytime.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider a web design program like [Artisteer](http://www.artisteer.com/), which includes pre-designed templates that you can fine-tune with a graphical interface, and then export as an ASP.NET website.

Answer (score 1):

**Get** an **ASP.NET template for Visual Studio** on Wiwet (**[www.wiwet.com](http://wiwet.com)**). **Wiwet** is similar to ThemForest but it **specialize on ASP.NET and MVC templates**.

I agree with the previous answers. Creating a good looking site requires the ability to design. Also, getting a HTML/PHP template from ThemForest and then trying to import it into .NET takes skill and a lot of time.

Check the YouTube video below. Having a good looking ASP.NET web app that is mobile ready in less than a minute is pretty awesome.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THuyqByZQN8&list=UUof9dyf9RpGSRFnGZ9Tpyww